# How to name two versions of the same object, where one has a smaller amount of data and one is the "complete" object

Tags: naming, class-design, naming-standards

What is the best way to name two classes that describe the same object, but where one of those classes does not hold the complete information? And should I make one of the classes inherit from the other?

I want to have (for the sake of example) an API that gets all people to display a list of names, and then when a person has been selected, another API that gets the detailed content for that person.

Here is an example of the classes I am currently using, and demonstrating my current decisions: the naming conventions, and that one should derive from the other.

```cs
    public class PersonBase
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person : PersonBase
    {
        public Date DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        // Other properties...
    }
```

EDIT: The reason I have chosen to separate into two classes for the same entity is because the database query for the complete `Person` is a lot more complex/intensive, and therefore I want a lightweight version that is used when searching for a particular person in a list.

Note that what I have called `PersonBase` actually contains some other properties that are used to filter on (you could imagine `IsManager` or similar), so in my opinion it does represent the person, but simply does not have the full information.

Comment: Instead of a class hierarchy, use containment. So, `PersonBase` has a method `getDetails()` which returns `Optional<Details>`.

Comment: @BobDalgleish that’ll be worth an answer!

Comment: @Mecki (and BobDalgleish) I've added some context for why I currently have two classes, and why I think they represent the same object.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I don't quite understand how your answer would look in code, I found [this thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1207579/Optional-property-in-a-Csharp-class) which discusses optional properties but I don't think it has any useful info for me. For the record I read the query results directly into the class using Dapper, so I can't easily set some kind of value indicating that all details are included. I will have a mapping layer, but the problem is still there for the DTO classes.

Answer (score 2):

Details on why you actually want to split an object into two objects would have been helpful to answer that question.

In your given example, I would name the objects `PersonName` and `Person`, as that's what the objects are: One just represents the name of a person and the other one a person as a whole. And this naming implies that inheritance is not meaningful as a person is not a person name and a person name is not a person. The correct relationship is a person has a person name.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't automatically use inheritance to represent variable amounts of data. It would be better to provide optional values from the base class, using `Optional` results.